How can i change navigation Items when a state is changed?
The idea of the app is a user can login to the app via firebase, i want to see if i can change the nav items dynamically dependeing on the state of the user has an account and its log to the app
Button(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),
    onClick = {
        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    if (auth.currentUser != null) {
                        navController.navigate(AppScreens.Courses.rout)
                    }
                }
            }
    },
)

The problem is that  navigates and the state changes; I log the valueand it changes but no updated navItem, I need to re-run the app to see the changes, I stop the execution and run it again and then I see the changes
val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
val user: FirebaseUser? by rememberUpdatedState(auth.currentUser)
val drawerState = rememberDrawerState(initialValue = DrawerValue.Closed)
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

ModalNavigationDrawer(
    drawerState = drawerState,
    gesturesEnabled = true,
    drawerContent = {
        ModalDrawerSheet {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                NavigationHeader()
                Divider(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(bottom = 10.dp)
                )
                if (user != null)
                    AdminNavItem(
                        navController = navController,
                        drawerState = drawerState,
                        scope = scope,
                    )
                else {
                    ClientNavItems(
                        navController = navController,
                        drawerState = drawerState,
                        scope = scope,
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    },
) {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.DarkGray,
                    titleContentColor = Color.White,
                ),
                title = {
                    Text(
                        text = "test text",
                    )
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    IconButton(onClick = {
                        scope.launch { drawerState.open() }
                    }) {
                        Icon(
                            tint = Color.White,
                            imageVector = Icons.Filled.Menu,
                            contentDescription = "Icono de Menu",
                        )
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    if (user != null) {
                        IconButton(onClick = { auth.signOut() }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.ExitToApp,
                                contentDescription = "Cerrar Sesion",
                                tint = Color.White,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                },
            )
        }
    ) { innerPadding ->
        MainNav(
            innerPadding = innerPadding,
            pagePaddingValues = pagePaddingValues,
            navController = navController,
        )
    }
}

